How to filter components of a quosure by class
I want to filter out components of a function's argument by class, motivated by this question (which looks for a function f so that f(c(mpg, gear)) is equivalent to select(mtcars, mpg)).
One way to do so is:
    f0 <- \(x){
      names_in <- x |>  
        enquo() |>
        quo_get_expr()
       mtcars |> select(names_in[[2]]) ## !
      }

... but I need to pick the second component of c(mpg, gear), because the first is c. However, a user might want to call f0(mpg) only, so the first quosure component has to be used instead of the second.
My idea was to Filter the list of components returned by quo_get_expr and drop what evaluates to class function (here: in environment mtcars). While Mapping does return the expected list of booleans, Filtering actually Reduces the list of components to a nested function (treating mpg etc. as calls):

    f1 <- function(x){
      names_in <- enquo(x) |> quo_get_expr()
      is_no_function <- \(nm) !(nm |> eval(envir = mtcars) |> inherits('function'))
      list(map_result = Map(names_in, f = is_no_function),
           filter_result = Filter(names_in, f = is_no_function)
      )
    }


output:
## > f1(c(mpg, gear))
## $map_result
## $map_result[[1]]
## [1] FALSE
## 
## $map_result[[2]]
## [1] TRUE
## 
## $map_result[[3]]
## [1] TRUE
## 
## 
## $filter_result
## mpg(gear) 

expected output:
## ...
## $filter_result
## [1] mpg  gear

While the original question already has an elegant solution with tidyselect, I'd be grateful for a hint why Filtering behaves like it does in this example, and what would be the proper way to proceed with the enquo output.

Are you expecting this to work with f1(mpg) as well? Your current code throws an error for that. Why are you trying to make c() work like this? Why not use f1(quos(mpg, gear)) or something like that which creates a nice container rather than worry about re-interpreting existing synax

MrFlick, I probably shouldn't have gone down the XY-road in the first place, but got hooked on just why Filter would nest the items.

Just check the class() of the result. It's not a list. it's a language object. That's typically how you represent calls.

I'm not sure the eval is really needed here. Do you intend to allow other functions like f1(sum(mpg, gear))? I think you can just more explictly work with the call and strip out the function.
f2 <- function(x){
  names_in <- enquo(x) |> quo_get_expr()
  if (is.symbol(names_in)) {return(list(names_in))}
  stopifnot(is.call(names_in))
  names_in <- as.list(names_in)
  stopifnot(names_in[[1]]==quote(`c`))
  return(names_in[-1])
}

Which returns
f2(c(mpg, gear))
# [[1]]
# mpg
# [[2]]
# gear

f2(mpg)
# [[1]]
# mpg

You get the unexpected result of mpg(gear) because what's being returned is a call object. See
x <- f1(c(mpg,gear))
class(x$filter_result)

All call objects begin with a symbol for the function, then a list of their parameters. So if you have a list like
as.call(list(quote(a), quote(b), quote(c)))
# a(b, c)

You can see it interprets the list as a call to the function a with parameters b and c

Just add as.list.  Below we use purrr::discard but Filter would work too.
library(purrr)
library(rlang)

f2 <- function(x) {
  x |>
    enquo() |>
    quo_get_expr() |>
    as.list() |>
    discard(~ is.function(eval(.x, mtcars)))
}

f2(c(mpg, gear))
## [[1]]
## mpg
##
## [[2]]
## gear

f2(mpg)
## [[1]]
## mpg


Unfortunately I can't accept two answers. While I like the lean style of your solution, the other one helped me wrap my brain around why I got the nested calls.
